# How to get Images from database to Listview c#

Tags: c#, sql, listview

I want to get database images show in listview but it does not work . I tried but can't any one can help .

```
       ListViewItem liv = new ListViewItem(read[0].ToString());
                liv.SubItems.Add(read[1].ToString());
                liv.SubItems.Add(read[2].ToString());
                liv.SubItems.Add(read[3].ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(liv);
```

Here on index[3] in database the images stored .

The error show in image

[image: error System.Byte[]]

Comment: what's the error, dear?

Comment: it show system.Byte[] only on index[3]

Comment: you should improve question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I can see, your image is stored in a Database and retrieved in ByteArray format. You need to convert the ByteArray stream to a Bitmap Image:

```
Image _image = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream((Byte[])read[3]));
```

Since this image has to be referenced in more than one method, define it at Class level.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;

Image _image;
```

To let a SubItem display the image, you need to Paint the items yourselft, so set the OwnerDraw property of your ListView:

```
listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
```

Get the items from your Data source:

```
(... LOOP ...)

//Define a new ListView Item...
ListViewItem _LVItem = new ListViewItem(read[0].ToString());
ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection _ItemsCollection = 
             new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection(_LVItem);

//... and SubItems
_ItemsCollection.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(_LVItem, read[1].ToString()));
_ItemsCollection.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(_LVItem, read[2].ToString()));
//No text here, this is where the image will be drawn
_ItemsCollection.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(_LVItem, ""));

//Create a new Bitmap using a MemoryStream
_image = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream((Byte[])read[3]));

listView1.Items.Add(_LVItem);

(... LOOP ...)
```

Create EventHandlers for `listView1.DrawColumnHeader` and `listView1.DrawSubItem`

```
//You need to draw both Headers...
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
   //Let the system draw these headers, nothing to do here
   e.DrawDefault = true;
}

//...  and SubItems
private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
   //If this is the column where the image is shown, draw it
   if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
   {
      //Position the image in the middle of its Column
      //This will be re-calculated when the Column is resized
      int _XLocation = (e.SubItem.Bounds.X + 
                       (e.SubItem.Bounds.Width / 2) - 
                       (e.SubItem.Bounds.Height / 2));

      //Draw the Image resized to the Height of the row
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, new Rectangle(_XLocation, e.SubItem.Bounds.Y, e.SubItem.Bounds.Height, e.SubItem.Bounds.Height));
   }

   //Draw the other columns using their pre-defined values
   e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
   e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, 
                         e.SubItem.Font, 
                         new SolidBrush(e.SubItem.ForeColor), 
                         e.SubItem.Bounds.Location.X, 
                         e.SubItem.Bounds.Location.Y);
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    // To Convert you byte array to Images you need to convert it to a memory stream first
    // You will need to add:
    // using System.IO;
    // And you need to add an ImageList named "imageList1" to your form.
    // Then Initialize the ImageList object with images.

    for (int i = 0; i < read.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(read[i]);
            this.imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromStream(memStream));
        }
        catch
        { MessageBox.Show( "Image at index ( " + i.ToString() + " ) is not an image file"); }
    }

    //Now You can assign the ImageList objects to your ListView.

    this.listView1.View = View.SmallIcon;
    this.listView1.SmallImageList = this.imageList1;

    for (int j = 0; j < this.imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
    {
        ListViewItem liv = new ListViewItem();
        liv.ImageIndex = j;
        this.listView1.Items.Add(liv);
    }
```